# Managing and providing html/template data bindings through the stack

Tags: go

Has anyone implemented a solution for managing view bindings while utilizing Go's `html/template`? Specifically, I'm hoping to find something that allows me to do things like:

- Set global during setup `Site.Title`
- Provide request-scoped variables, like `CurrentURL`
- Then, at the `Render` step, simply provide the `http.Handler`-specific variables, to then be combined and provided to the template.

An example existing application would be something like this (I use `unrolled/render` for layout inheritance, but that is replaceable):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
    "github.com/unrolled/render"
)

type HelloBinding struct {
    Name string
}

func helloHandler(render *render.Render) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _ = render.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "hello", &HelloBinding{
            Name: "World!",
        })
    }
}

func main() {
    port, ok := os.LookupEnv("PORT")
    if !ok {
        port = "8080"
    }

    render := render.New(render.Options{
        Directory:     "templates",
        Layout:        "layout",
        Extensions:    []string{".html"},
        IsDevelopment: true,
    })

    r := chi.NewMux()

    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    r.Get("/", helloHandler(render))

    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:    net.JoinHostPort("", port),
        Handler: r,
    }

    log.Printf("http server listening at %s\n", httpServer.Addr)
    if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    {{ yield }}

</body>
</html>
```

And a shared view

```
Hello, {{ .Name }}
```

---

In an ideal solution, something like this would be possible:

> **Warning:** Pseudo code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
    "github.com/go-chi/chi/middleware"
    "github.com/unrolled/render"
)

type GlobalBinding struct {
    Title string
}

type RequestBinding struct {
    CurrentURL string
}

type HelloBinding struct {
    Name string
}

func helloHandler(render *render.Render) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _ = render.HTML(w, http.StatusOK, "hello", &HelloBinding{
            Name: "World!",
        })
    }
}

func main() {
    port, ok := os.LookupEnv("PORT")
    if !ok {
        port = "8080"
    }

    render := render.New(render.Options{
        Directory:     "templates",
        Layout:        "layout",
        Extensions:    []string{".html"},
        IsDevelopment: true,
    })

    // Binds data to be used
    render.Bind(GlobalBindings{
        Title: "My Site",
    })

    r := chi.NewMux()

    r.Use(middleware.Logger)
    r.Use(middleware.Recoverer)

    // Binds data for the request context only
    r.Use(func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            render.BindContext(r.Context, RequestBinding{
                CurrentURL: r.URL.String(),
            })
            next(w, r)
        }
    })

    r.Get("/", helloHandler(render))

    httpServer := &http.Server{
        Addr:    net.JoinHostPort("", port),
        Handler: r,
    }

    log.Printf("http server listening at %s\n", httpServer.Addr)
    if err := httpServer.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

Allowing me to change things like that layout to:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ .Global.Title }}</title>
</head>
<body>

    {{ .CurrentURL }}

    {{ yield }}

</body>
</html>
```

And things are merged and bound without much thought by the individual handler.

---

Hope you guys have some solutions! I've been struggling at this for a while.

Comment: Maybe try reddit? As is, this question is off-topic for SO - requests for 3rd-party libraries/resources are off-topic, and vaguely asking for "clever solutions" to using templates is too broad. If you have a specific question about using templates that might be something SO can help with.

Comment: I didn't exactly think what I was asking for here was vague? This is a common problem expressed in most programming languages that I have yet to see solved in Go close to the manner described here. I'm happy to change my wording if that makes it more appropriate, but something like this is very accomplishable within Go, I just assumed that people would have existing libraries rather than needing to write it out.

Comment: I'm not saying it's not possible in Go, I'm just saying it's [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: To me asking for a library yes, but what I'm after here is someones solution or thoughts around how this can be accomplished. I edited to remove my request for a library, thank you for pointing that out to me.

Comment: Why isn't your ideal solution possible?

Answer (score -1):

Not in `html/template` but consider using quicktemplates

https://github.com/valyala/quicktemplate

It's designed around regular code so your renderers are just functions that can take arbitrary parameters (and interfaces). You can import packages and call regular functions and access global variables.

It's a lot more comfortable to work with than the builtin templating engine, plus you get static type checking. The only downside is you need to rebuild/restart after editing to reflect changes.

Comment: I'm not so muhc looking how to render templates, but how to deal with dependency-injection-like flow of data bindings.

Comment: My point is with the builtin template engine there's really no simple and obvious way to do what you want. But with this other engine I'm suggesting I think what you want to do would be more or less straight forward.